# localstack+ssm how to configure parameters from docker compose

Tags: docker-compose, localstack

I am trying to run locally localstack with SSM, the default port I am getting is 4566
but when trying to init params via the docer compose I just ant figure oout how I do it from the docker compose
this is what I have :

```
localstack:
image: 'localstack/localstack'
ports:
  - '4566:4566'
environment:
  - SERVICES=lambda,ssm
  - DEBUG=1
  - DATA_DIR=${DATA_DIR- }
  - PORT_WEB_UI=${PORT_WEB_UI- }
  - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=local
  - KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY=${KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY- }
  - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
  - HOST_TMP_FOLDER=${TMPDIR}
volumes:
  - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/tmp/localstack"
  - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

I am trying to figure out how to pass multiple values from the docker-compose file
I am aware it can be done after by aws cli

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 ssm put-parameter --name "/dev/some_key" --type String --value "vaue" --overwrite --region "us-east-1"
```

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for anyone who is still looking for answers:
Localstack has a few [lifecycle stages](https://docs.localstack.cloud/references/init-hooks/#lifecycle-stages-and-hooks) which we can hook on to. In this case, since we want to create SSM parameters in localstack  after localstack is ready, we would want to use the init/ready.d hook. Which means, create a script with the awlocal command and mount it into /etc/localstack/init/ready.d/.

```
   volumes:
      - "/path/to/init-aws.sh:/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/init-aws.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for anyone who is still looking for answers:
LocalStack has a few [lifecycle stages](https://docs.localstack.cloud/references/init-hooks/#lifecycle-stages-and-hooks) which we can hook on to. In your case, since you want to create SSM parameters in LocalStack  after LocalStack is ready, you would want to use the init/ready.d hook. Which means, create a script with your awlocal command and mount it into /etc/localstack/init/ready.d/. If you watch the logs after LocalStack is up and ready, you would see the script getting applied and the SSM parameters getting created.

```
   volumes:
      - "/path/to/init-aws.sh:/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/init-aws.sh"
```